# Render then append new component after click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

Is it possible to render and append a new component after click? I have my calendar component

```
return (
  <span
    key={date.toString()}
    className={"day" + (isToday ? " today" : "") + (isCurrentMonth ? "" : " different-month") + (date.isSame(selected) ? " selected" : "")}
    onClick={()=>select(day)}>{number}</span>
);
```

onClick I want to render my jsWindow Component

```
render(){
    return (
        <div className="js-window">
        {console.log(this.props)}
            <Icon icon={close} className="closeBtn" size={24} onClick={(e)=>e.target.parentNode.parentNode.remove()}/>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    )
}
```

After click close icon I want remove JsWindow.

Comment: rather use a state to make the _jsWindow_ component toggle appearance. Toggle the state in the _calendar_ component

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional rendering:

```
{ condition && <Component /> }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the selected day in component state and render your component based on that. On click you set or reset the state, which will trigger a rerender.

Basic example to get you started:

```
state = {
    day: undefined
}

selectDay = day => {
    this.setState({day});
};

resetDay = () => {
    this.setState({day: undefined});
};

render(){
    const day = this.state.day;
    return  day ? (
            <div className="js-window">
                <Icon icon={close} className="closeBtn" size={24} onClick={this.resetDay}/>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        ) : (
            <span key={date.toString()} className={} onClick={()=>this.selectDay(day)}>{number}</span>
        )
    )
}
```